# Storing an ArrayList as a persistent data structure

Tags: android, kotlin

I am developing a todo list app in which I have a ArrayList of categories for the individual todos like Personal, Work etc. This todo list is stored as a persistent storage via Room library. Now I need to provide the functionality to user to create their own lists. For that I need the categories ArrayList to also be persistent. How can I do this?

Comment: Do you mean users can add new categories?

Comment: If all Todos, from any list/category, have same data structure, then save them in a same table and filter them using the category which has its own table listing all the categories.

Comment: @gioravered yes.

Comment: @LalitFauzdar yes but won't this result in the following situation - suppose user created a category A, created a todo in it, and then deleted that todo. This would result in the loss of that category too. I don't want that. It should be upto the user to whether delete this category/list or not, regardless of whether it contains some todos or not.

Comment: I said list all the todo items in a single table with the category as a field, and the category will be a part of a separate table Categories. And, to display the content, first list all the categories in the frontend, then, filter the todo items based on the category and load them in the frontend. That is how it is done. So, even if any category has 0 items, it will be listed there for the user to interact with it.

Comment: Yeah you're getting into real relational database territory now! Separate table to store categories, your todos records reference a category ID so it can be looked up in the other table. Here's the Room docs about it, but if you don't know what a JOIN is, you should go read a SQL tutorial and get a handle on the basics: https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/accessing-data#multiple-tables